# "Blocked or was Blocked By"

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Time to Reflect](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTime%20to%20Reflect%5d) says:

> Exile target creature that blocked or was blocked by a Zombie this turn.

It's completely and utterly clear what the *intention* of this card is. That you can exile a target if that target blocked a Zombie, or if that target was blocked by a Zombie

However, what it ***says*** is `that blocked or was blocked by a Zombie`.

Magic is a rules-lawyer, literal-text-interpretation game, and that sentence (on its own) does *not* link `that blocked` to `a Zombie`.

If that sentence had been "return any creature that died or was blocked by a Zombie to hand, whatever zone it is currently in" then you would clearly allow it to target any creature that died for any reason whether or not it pertained to a Zombie.

A) Is there a specific ruling clarifying this anywhere (there's no card-ruling on The Gatherer)?
B) If not, then what would happen at an FNM or at a formal tournament if I tried to argue my case?

Comment: Your example with "died" is read as two separate things because you can't have a creature that "died by a Zombie", not because there's no link whatsoever. I'd try other examples before you try to base too much on "literal" reading in that vein, e.g. "Anyone who jogs or runs by the pool will be asked to leave."

Comment: @Jefromi On the other hand, "No drinking or eating messy foods during the show" requires the opposite interpretation. So it's not always one or the other. There might not be a better answer here than the required use of the most common-sense reading.

Comment: @GendoIkari That's pretty much my point: there is no literal reading that's always correct, and you have to use some amount of common sense to understand the language. So when the OP says it's clear what the intention is, well, that's how we know what it means, not the rules-lawyer stuff that follows.

Comment: Except that Magic is TOTALLY a rules lawyer game. It is a legitamate way to play the game to look for ways that the specific functionality of cards interacts with each other. See also Humility v Opalescence, the Chaos Orb legend, and the size of the rule book and the number of card rulings in general.

Comment: If the game was intended to be played on the basis of "what was obviously intended", none of that would be necessary.

Comment: Magic is a rules lawyer game, but the language used on cards and in the rules is not necessarily so. For example, there are cards with a certain name, and the card's text references itself with an abridged version of that name. Fictional example: A creature named *Borat, Vanguard of Khasakhstan* and with the card text "Whenever Borat attacks, you win the game". That ability of *Borat, Vanguard of Khasakhstan* is still functional, even though technically it references some other card or permanent with the full name "Borat".

Comment: Therefore, the 99.9% obvious-but-technically-possibly-not-quite-waterproof interpretation is the correct one, except that hasn't been spelled out in the CompRules.

Comment: "My opponent's textless Cryptic Command doesn't *say* it does anything, so *technically* it shouldn't do anything, right?"

Comment: Card name: [Animar, Soul of Elements](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=236504). Official Oracle card text, among others: "Creature spells you cast cost 1 less to cast for each +1/+1 counter on Animar."

Comment: Language is a tool for communicating, and Magic cards use it to communicate their functionality. Not all cards are written perfectly unambiguously, but every card can in fact be interpreted on the basis of "what was obviously intended" *unless* a rule specifically ascribes a different meaning to a word, phrase, or sentence structure on the card.

Comment: @Brondahl Yes, there are a lot of rules, and often a lot to be gained by thoroughly understanding them. That doesn't mean that absolutely everything in the entire game is specified solely by the rules without any reliance on understanding English. I wasn't saying that the *entire* game was played based on understanding intent, but rather that there are bits here and there which require some understanding beyond what's carefully spelled out by the rules.

Comment: fwiw, I'm not sure what the rules say, but if you start going rules-lawyer on me for something with such clear intent as this, I wouldn't enjoy playing with you.

Answer (score 4):

The sentence on that card is to be read as "Exile target creature that (blocked or was blocked) by a Zombie this turn"; parentheses mine. Both "blocked" and "was blocked" are linked to "by a zombie". You can confirm that from the rulings at the bottom of the oracle page of Time to Reflect that you linked:

> Time to Reflect only cares that the second creature was a Zombie at the moment it blocked or became blocked by the target creature. If that Zombie has become a non-Zombie creature or left the battlefield, Time to Reflect can still target the first creature.

The [two other cards](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=+%5B%22blocked%20or%20was%20blocked%22%5D%7C%7Ctext=+%5B%22blocked%20or%20was%20blocked%22%5D) containing the phrase "blocked or was blocked" are [Heat Stroke](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHeat%20Stroke%5d) and [Sea Troll](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSea%20Troll%5d). Heat Stroke in particular would not make sense if "blocked" and "was blocked" were not both connected to "this turn", because "blocked" would not have any limitation in time. Similar for Sea Troll and Time to Reflect; if "blocked" was meant to stand alone, it would still contain some sort of time limitation, even if was something like "this game".

As for your second question regarding Time to Reflect, it can only target creatures. A creature is any object on the battlefield whose card types includes "creature" and that has values for its power and toughness. A creature card in the graveyard or anywhere else but the battlefield is not a creature, therefore it's never a valid target for Time to Reflect. Whenever you read a combination of card types without additional qualifiers, such as "creature", "land", "artifact enchantment" and so on, that is always shorthand for a *permanent* of those types, i.e. "creature permanent", "land permanent", "artifact enchantment permanent", and so on. *Objects* are *permanents* if and only if they are on the battlefield.

> 110.1. A permanent is a card or token on the battlefield. A permanent remains on the battlefield indefinitely. A card or token becomes a permanent as it enters the battlefield and it stops being a permanent as it’s moved to another zone by an effect or rule.
>
> 114.2. Only permanents are legal targets for spells and abilities, unless a spell or ability (a) specifies that it can target an object in another zone or a player, (b) targets an object that can’t exist on the battlefield, such as a spell or ability, or (c) targets a zone.

Comment: I'm confused where your last paragraph is coming from. Nothing in his question shows any confusion over what "creature" means, or asks a second question that you are answering by defining a permanent.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that Sea Troll's printed text is actually clearer on the meaning, and shows that both parts pertain to "blue creature".

Comment: @Hackworth What's all that "only target's creatures", this is the defn of a permanent stuff about? I haven't said anything about that? -1

Comment: So, your initial answer is just to state that <the obvious interpretation> is the correct one. I already stated that I could see the obvious interpretation and could see that this was what was intended. My question is whether there is anything that anyone could cite to PROVE that this is the only acceptable interpretation. The ruling on that card, is a tenuous citation at best, since it doesn't directly address the point. And you cite Heat Wave ... but on what grounds are you asserting that Heat Wave only applies to creatures that blocked this turn? What ruling do you have that supports that?

Comment: I mentioned the part about targeting because OP seemed to be confused about it, since he mentioned targeting a creature card in the graveyard, one that died from combat with a zombie.

Comment: You've misread something... he used an example of a different but similar sentence, which involved a creature that had died, but he wasn't asking anything about if you can target creatures in the graveyard. I suppose he should have said "creature card" instead of "creature" in his hypothetical example, but it seems clear he didn't have any confusion over that point.

Comment: @Hackworth, the point there was entirely about the grammatical validity of my interpretation, and that it would be *normal* interpretation under some circumstances.

Comment: Let me just say that you are massively overthinking this issue. Card text has to be interpreted according to the rules of the English language. I don't know those rules well enough to argue authoritatively either way; we would have to get an English major involved for that. All I know is that the obvious interpretation is correct in this case, for which I've tried to give circumstantial evidence because there is no rules reference that directly answers your case. Any judge, whether at FNM or elsewhere, would tell you the same.

Comment: I do know enough about the English language to say that there are ways to make the opposite interpretation true. It could be worded e.g. as "by a creature that blocked this turn, or that was blocked by a Zombie this turn". But it wasn't worded like that or anything else that even hints at the possibility that you brought up, so I have no reason to believe that to be true.

Comment: And there are also very simple formulations that unambiguously make it the 'default' interpretation: `Exile Target creation that blocked a Zombie this turn, or was blocked by a Zombie this turn` or `Exile Target creation that blocked, or was blocked by, a Zombie this turn` (Note punctuation). :shrugs:

Comment: And I think if you could tell me that, with the benefit of much judging experience, you can confidently assert that there is definitely no rules reference to cite, either here or for other similar card. And similarly that you can, with good reason, assert that any judge would rule as such, then I'd consider that a sound answer to my question :)]

Comment: Both of your examples are less readable than the original. Card templating has to find a middle ground between readability and technical correctness, in order to let players focus on the game rather than deciphering card text.

Comment: "By" should be inside the parentheses, it is prepositional to the second use of "blocked" and makes no sense attached to the first use. "... that (...) a Zombie ..." should end up being the structure. I mean, if we're arguing about rule technicalities and all :)

Answer (score -2):

You don't get to interpret the English on cards. Magic isn't a rules-lawyer game, it's a rules-programmer game, where every word and formatting structure has a VERY specific meaning. There is no rules reference that adds (parentheses) to "Exile target creature that (blocked or was blocked by) a Zombie this turn" to remove ambiguity in the way you want, but I can guarantee you that there is no certified judge who will support the interpretation that you want to push. Thinking of the text on cards in terms of English, with all its imperfections and ambiguities, is a mistake.

But if you insist, here are some other ideas for you to push;

- [Lightning Bolt](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lightning%20Bolt) can target an opponent who has [Leyline of Sanctity](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Leyline%20of%20Sanctity), because it says "(target creature) or (player)".
- [Chainer's Edict](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Chainer%27s%20Edict)'s flashback reminder text says to cast it from graveyard, "Then exile it". Doesn't it just get exiled from the stack immediately?
- [Hero's Downfall](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hero%27s%20Downfall) targets planeswalkers. Aren't the players planeswalkers in this game?

Comment: Your reasoning is off. If a player is supposed to not interpret the English on cards, and there is no rules reference to answer the question, then what is there to go by? Hint: It's absolutely necessary to interpret cards and rules according to the rules of the English language, exactly because there is no machine-readable text on human-readable cards. For example, rule 608.2c, in part, reads: "Don’t just apply effects step by step without thinking in these cases—read the whole text and **apply the rules of English to the text**.", emphasis mine.

Comment: @Hackworth The issue here is that English has an ambiguity, but Magic doesn't. There is one interpretation of that sentence which is correct, and quibbling about it doesn't change anything, which is why Magic is closer to "rules programming" than "rules lawyering".

If a ruling is needed, "no judge would ever let you do that" is sufficient. The writers of the CR didn't feel the need to explain reading, so there isn't much relevant literature there.

Comment: The fact is that Magic cards are written in English, and there are sometimes ambiguities in card text that require interpretation. Sometimes, even with Magic cards, you need a little common sense to determine which antecedent of a pronoun makes the most sense, or which interpretation of a sentence structure most likely matches the author's intention. This ambiguity is one of the reasons Magic cards have rulings and errata.